# Sort data frame in R by value and one group of multiple group column

Tags: r, dataframe

I can't find how to combine two specific conditions.

Imagine we have two columns. First column is presenting salary and second column the city as below:

```
df <- data.frame(salary = c(100, 200, 150, 300, 350),
city = c("nyc", "la", "la", "nyc", "la"))
```

Now the case is to show only the values for `city = "nyc"` and `salary` in descending order. How to show only one group from column containing multiple groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We subset the rows where the 'City' is "nyc" and then `order` the 'Salary' column in descending order

```
df1 <- df[df$City == 'nyc',]
df1[order(-df1$Salary),]
#    Salary City
#4    300  nyc
#1    100  nyc
```

If we need only the 'Salary' column

```
with(df, sort(Salary[City == 'nyc'], decreasing = TRUE))
#[1] 300 100
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    filter(City == 'nyc') %>%
    arrange(desc(Salary))
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(Salary = c(100, 200, 150, 300, 350), 
                 City = c("nyc", "la", "la", "nyc", "la"))
```